# Unable to pass Stripe token to backend using Angular and Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to process a Stripe charge in Angular using the [Angular Payments](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments) module. I am able to get the token from Stripe, but receive the following error on the client side when I attempt to submit the token to my Express server:

> ReferenceError: token is not defined

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Here's the relevant code:

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('PaymentFormCtrl',
  function($scope){
    $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
    console.log('response', status, response);
    if(response.error) {
      console.log('error');// there was an error. Fix it.
    } else {
      console.log('no error');
      token = response.id;
      return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/payments', payment);
    }
  };
});
```

HTML for form:

```
<form stripe-form="handleStripe" name="myForm">

  <div class="span3">
    <label for="">Card number</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" payments-type-model="type" ng-class="myForm.number.$card.type"/>
  </div>

  <div class="span1">
    <label for="">Expiry</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" payments-format="expiry" />
  </div>

  <div class="span3">
    <label for="">Name on card </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
  </div>

  <div class="span1">
    <label for="">CVC</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" payments-format="cvc" payments-type-model="type"/>
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Server Javascript:

```
apiRouter.route('/payments')

.post(function(req, res) {

  var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;

  var charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 1000, 
        currency: "usd",
        source: stripeToken,
        description: "payinguser@example.com"
    }, function (err, charge) {
        if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could be a problem with variable declarations depending on whether you're running this under strict mode or not. Quick test, do you get the same Reference Error if you change 'token' to 'var token'?

Comment: @Martyn Davies When I use `var token` instead, i get the following error: `$http is not defined`

Comment: Pass $http into your function along with $scope, so it's function($scope, $http) {}

Answer (score 0):

One thing to fix for sure is that in the server side your request is '`req'` yet you are trying to get the token from

`request.body.stripeToken`,

should be

`req.body.stripeToken`